# control a lot of ifs in calculating number value of String in Java like ("-3.1+0.12*0.0023-34.1/2.1")

Tags: java, algorithm, flowchart

I wanna to solve my Homework about calculating number value of String in Java like `"-3.1+0.12*0.0023-34.1/2.1"`

I have limitations to use only Arrays and Strings and not use recursive functions (as first year student)

What I try?
I am trying to solve it by parsing string char by char.

I try this method only for + and - :

```
public static double CalcPlusMinus(String s) {
    double A[] = new double[10000];
    if ((s.charAt(0) != '+') && (s.charAt(0) != '-'))
        s = '+' + s;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < s.length()) {
        int flag = 1;
        if (s.charAt(i) == '-')
            flag = -1;
        i++;
        double m = 0;
        int end = 0;
        if ((s.charAt(i) >= '0') && (s.charAt(i) <= '9'))
            while ((s.charAt(i) >= '0') && (s.charAt(i) <= '9')) {
                m = m * 10 + (s.charAt(i) - '0');
                i++;
                if (i >= s.length()) {
                    end = 1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        if (end == 0)
            if (s.charAt(i) == '.') {
                i++;
                double x = 10;
                while ((s.charAt(i) >= '0') && (s.charAt(i) <= '9')) {
                    m = m + ((s.charAt(i) - '0') / x);
                    x *= 10;
                    i++;
                    if (i >= s.length())
                        break;
                }
            }
        A[j++] = m * flag;
    }
    A[A.length - 1] = j;
    for (int m = (int) A[A.length - 1] - 1; m > 0; m--) {
        A[m - 1] = A[m] + A[m - 1];
    }
    return A[0];
}
```

I am trying to add * and / to this method

**But my main question is** : how can I control a lot of if-then-else in my code?

Is there any **formal way** to control a lot of ifs in the code?
I know flowcharts, but the flowchart turn to a very big picture too!!

Comment: You mean in a switch and case sense of control?

Comment: You can use ` switch` statement.

Comment: thanks for reply, my problem is not using if or switch, I am looking a way to control a lots of ifs. I am getting so puzzled and I lose the control of my source code. By drawing flowcharts, I faced with a big paper. Is there a strategy to control this puzzler code?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but, Try / Catch statements with if statements within to throw specific exceptions if certain actions happen.

Comment: I don't see a single `else` in your code and not that many `if`s either. The code can be simplified - you can drop the first `if ((s.charAt(i) >= '0') && (s.charAt(i) <= '9'))` since the `while` loop on the next line already does the same. Also, you're using `end` as a flag so you should declare it as `boolean end = false;`, use `end = true;` and `if (!end && s.charAt(i) == '.')` to combine two if-statements into one. And what you called `flag`, you should call `sign` because that's what it is.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt thanks a lot for your very useful tips, I trying to use them. And sorry for my question. I did not post complete code. I added * and / support to my method. Also in next step of homework, I should add parenthesis support and math functions support like `-2.1+sin(0.23)*(3.1-4.4)`, so I have a lot of ifs (not else).

Comment: You have lots of states in your problem, you should model them to overcome it's complexity. You can use UML State Diagrams or DFA or NFA of Automata to model your problem instead of flowcharts.

Comment: thanks a lot, useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should have 3 separate steps:

1. parsing/tokenization - spiting "-3.1+0.12*0.0023-34.1/2.1" into:
   "-" "3.1" "+" "0.12" "*" "0.0023" "-" "34.1" "/" "2.1"
2. convert to [Reverse Polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation), using array as a stack
3. calculating the value of expression